# Allow to change keyboard language while password field is focused

Tags: firefox, password, language-support

If I try to change keyboard language when password input is focused, the language changes, but instantly changes back. I get this behavior in Ubuntu 18.04, Firefox 72. I want to use correct language for my password, but I have to select it before clicking on password field.

Any suggestions, how could I remove this restriction? I want to be able to change my language when password field is on focus.

I used Alt+Shift shortcut to change the language. In Ubuntu 20.04 this key combination is no more available.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you have to set back your preferred keyboard layout everytime you login. If it is the case, you can go to "Settings - Region and Language - Input sources" and set the language you want to login with in first position.
Also, in that same section, when you click on Options, you can set "Allow different sources for each window" or "Use the same source for all windows", depending on your preferences.
Hope this answers to your question.